# How to have a class which is a property of something?

Tags: javascript, class, object, properties, ecmascript-6

I have a javascript object `menu`, and I want to add a property `controller` which should be a constructor. However, the following gives a syntax error:

```
class menu.foobar {
    // stuff here
}
```

What is the right way to do this?

Comment: `const menu = { foobar: class { … } }`? It's the same as if you had a `function` declaration.

Answer (score 1):

Use a *class expression*:

```
menu.foobar = class {}
```